# Trying to deploy to Azure using GitHub actions

Tags: yaml, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-deployment

I'm using the following YAML to deploy to an Azure App Service:

```
- name: dotnet publish
  run: dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapp' 

# Deploy to Azure Web apps
- name: 'Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials'
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with: 
    app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }} 
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE  }} 
    package: '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapp'
```

To add the AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE I created a secret and pasted the publish profile that I downloaded from:

```
App Service -> Get Publish Profile
```

Which gave me a file named `myapp.PublishSettings`, and is an XML file.

When I try to run this, I get the error:

```
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Publish profile is invalid for app-name and slot-name provided. Provide correct publish profile credentials for app.
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 4):

It's obviously that the value of `AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE` in your GitHub repository is not correct.
Here is the official document you could follow with: [Deploy to App Service using GitHub Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel)

There are two things you should check:

**1. Make sure you copy the whole content of publish profile. Do not change anything.**

**2. Check if the publish profile is downloaded from your `AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME`.**

Comment: Please let me know if it helps or not, tahnks. @stannage

Comment: I had sort of come to the same conclusion, although the two points that you raised I am pretty confident that I've followed (tried re-downloading the profile and pasting it in to make sure there was nothing strange about it).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer before this one, AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME specified on your workflow must be same as the name given to App Service

Comment: forgot this haha